# custom sorting function with struct

Tags: c++, c, sorting, struct

So, I have a problem with this sorting function, that I wrote to sort struct.

My initial thought was to have a `while` cycle until there is no changes happening, and inside have `for` cycle that goes through an `array[10]`, comparing two elements that are next to each other. If next element is larger than previous one, they are exchanged, and iterator thrown back to zero.

Everything kind of works, except for the first element, which is not highest. From second to last, everything is fine.

Any pointers, to where I have made a mistake? Code seems fine to me...
I know I could have used `<algorithm>`, but I am supposed to write my own function for this.

```
void izvadaPecRez(Pari masivs[])
{
    Pari temp;
    bool change;
    int i;
    while(change!=false)
    {
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(masivs[i+1].kopejais>masivs[i].kopejais)
            {
                temp=masivs[i];
                masivs[i]=masivs[i+1];
                masivs[i+1]=temp;
                change=true;
                i=0;
            }
            else
            {
                change=false;
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printone(masivs, i);
}
```

Comment: Are you hard-coding the count of objects? Don't.

Comment: You can write ` while(change!=false)` as `while(change == true)`. this is more readable. and `change` is not initialized, so the default value will be `false`

Comment: @RakibulHasan `while( change )`

Comment: @Rakibul Hasan the default value of an uninitialized variable is undefined. Especially Visual studio likes to initialize stack variables with `0xcdcd...cd` in Debug mode, this would lead to change being true

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot to initialize change, I was messing around with the function, and I had it initialized in a part what I deleted before posting, as it did nothing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i=0` is going to happen right before the increment in the for loop runs, so the effect of the statement will be that `i==1` in the next loop. The easiest way to get your intended behavior is to just `break` from the for-loop after you swap the elements (don't worry, it'll only break the for-loop, not the while-loop). You should also just set `change=false` at the top of the while-loop, rather than setting it whenever you *don't* swap elements.

Comment: @user3665674: You got to be aware, however, that breaking out after the swap  in general leads to slower performance ... to avoid, simply insert another boolean `bool temp=false;` inside the loop, replace any occurence of `change` by `temp`, and at the end of the loop set `change=temp` (see edit of my answer below). But I guess efficiency is not of your concern, else you wouldn't reject `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead for sorting (still untested):

```
#include<array>
#include<functional>
#include<algorithm>

std::array<Pari,100> masivs;
auto compare=[](const Pari& a, const Pari& b) {return a.kopejais<b.kopejais;};
std::sort(masivs.begin(), masivs.end(), compare);
```

Here, instead of a normal array, `std::array` is used. Next, a custom comparison lambda-function is defined and passed to `std::sort`.

I don't know whether it does exactly the same as your code, but at least will sort your classes according to the entry `kopejais`.

---

**EDIT:** Here is a version of your code which should work faster than the one in the accepted answer:

```
void izvadaPecRez(Pari masivs[])
{
    bool change=true;
    while(change==true)
    {
        change=false;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(masivs[i+1].kopejais > masivs[i].kopejais)
            {
                std::swap(masivs[i], masivs[i+1]);
                change=true;
            }
        }
    };

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printone(masivs, i);
}
```

The reason is that you are not repeatedly looping over already ordered parts of the array, which is done by using `break` after the swap.

Comment: Quoth the OP: "I know I could have used <algorithm>, but I am supposed to write my own function for this."